# How to make push notification appear in foreground when app is open

Tags: ios, react-native, onesignal

I am using push notification service in my app. When app is in background I am able to get notification on notification screen(screen shown when we swipe down from top of iOS device) or when I close my app afterward, But if application is open I can't even get/see the notification. please if anybody know how to solve this any help would be appreciate.

here is what it look like inside AppDelegate file

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    [FIRApp configure];
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzcasdsr4ZdsdsA7BIxJxb6g3XE"];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [super applicationWillEnterForeground:application];
}


#pragma mark - Handling URLs

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [super application:app openURL:url options:options];
}



#pragma mark - Notifications

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)token
{
  [super application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:token];
}



@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the following code in AppDelegate to receive notification when the app is in Foreground.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
}
```

Ensure AppDelegate conforms to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol and set `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Please find the doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter).

EDIT 2:

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface NFAppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    [FIRApp configure];
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzcasdsr4ZdsdsA7BIxJxb6g3XE"];
    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [super applicationWillEnterForeground:application];
}


#pragma mark - Handling URLs

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [super application:app openURL:url options:options];
}



#pragma mark - Notifications

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)token
{
  [super application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:token];
}

#pragma mark - UNNotificationCenterDelegate
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert|UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);
}


@end
```

Comment: when I look inside AppDelegate and try to out your code inside it and seems like quite different and sure I got an error for that because all the function in AppDelegate look like down below for example @Anand

Comment: `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)token
{
  [super application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:token];
}`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still really new at this ios native code, so I just edited my question to show you what my AppDelegate look like maybe you can help me to apply the **func userNotificationCenter()** inside it. thank you @Anand

Comment: Please see my EDIT2.

Comment: I got an error in `@implementation AppDelegate <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>` that said **@implementation declaration cannot be protocol qualified, Replace '<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>' with ''  **. Do you what it's that mean? @Anand